# correct way to check user input with scanner

Tags: java, syntax, java.util.scanner

I'm very new to programming, I've wrote an app for working the area out of certain shapes.

I have the `AreaCalculations` in another class can provide if needed but that works fine.

My problem is checking  when the user types a character instead of a double. As you can see from my code i got it to work by using a while loop and `(!reader.NextDouble())` .

This works but i then have to repeat the question. I could do this throughout the program but is there an easier/tidier way of doing this???

Thanks,

Craig

My code so far :

```
package areaprog;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Mainprog {


public static void main (String [] args){

    //Area Menu Selection
    System.out.println("What shape do you need to know the area of?\n" +
    "1: Square?\n" +
    "2: Rectangle?\n" +
    "3: Triangle?\n" +
    "4: Circle? \n" +
    "5: Exit\n"     
    );

    //User input for menu

    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Number: ");

    //Menu syntax checking
    while (!reader.hasNextDouble())
    {
        System.out.println("Thats not a number you tool.\n");
        System.out.println("Now pick again\n" +
                "1: Square?\n" +
                "2: Rectangle?\n" +
                "3: Triangle?\n" +
                "4: Circle? \n" +
                "5: Exit\n"     
                );

        reader.next(); //ask for next token?        
    }               
        double input = reader.nextDouble();
        reader.nextLine();



    //Depending on user selection, depends on what method is called using switch.
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Square selection
    if (input == 1){
        System.out.println("What is a length of 1 side of the Square?\n");
            double s1 = scan.nextDouble();
            double SqAns = AreaCalculator.getSquareArea(s1);
            System.out.println("The area of you square is: " + SqAns);

                   }

    //Rectangle selection    
        if (input == 2){
        System.out.println("What is the width of your rectangle?.\n");
            double r1 = scan.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("What is the height of your rectangle?\n");
            double r2 = scan.nextDouble();
            double RecAns = AreaCalculator.getRectArea(r1, r2);
        System.out.println("The area of your rectangle is: " + RecAns);    
        }
    //Triangle selection
    if (input == 3){
        System.out.println("What is the base length of the triangle?.");
            double t1 = scan.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("What is the height of your triangle?");
            double t2 = scan.nextDouble();
            double TriAns = AreaCalculator.getTriArea(t1, t2);
        System.out.println("The area of your triangle is " + TriAns);
    }
    //Circle selection
    if (input == 4){
        System.out.println("What is the radius of your circle?.");
            double c1 = scan.nextDouble();
            double CircAns = AreaCalculator.getCircleArea(c1);
        System.out.println("The area of your circle is " + CircAns);    

    }
    //Exit application
    if (input == 5){
        System.out.println("Goodbye.");

    }


}

}
```

Ok so I've added in a Exception to catch the error. So its a bit cleaner now in the way it handles people not using intergers.

Number: 
1
What is a length of 1 side of the Square?

a
Why are you trying to be clever? use an interger.

But then the program just ends.... How would i either get them back to the main menu or even get them to re-input there last effort?

Thanks,

Craig

Answer (score 0):

As far as menu driven programs are concerned,its well and good.But as you said:
*"This works but i then have to repeat the question."*

So read [Exception handling tutorial in java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/)

So, your code will look something like this :

```
    try
   {
    System.out.println("Thats not a number you tool.\n");
    System.out.println("Now pick again\n" +
            "1: Square?\n" +
            "2: Rectangle?\n" +
            "3: Triangle?\n" +
            "4: Circle? \n" +
            "5: Exit\n"
            );


input = reader.nextDouble();
 }
   catch(InputMismatchException err)
    {
  System.out.print(err.getMessage());

     }
```

Don't forget to import `import java.util.InputMismatchException` or `import java.util.*`

And try to declare variables outside the `try` block, may not be visible outside.